# Unable to embed fonts in PowerPoint

Tags: fonts, ms-office, powerpoint, truetype

I'm trying to embed fonts on a PowerPoint template I'm working on, but every time I try to save it, I get an error saying that the font cannot be embedded because it's not truetype. I've looked through every slide and made sure that the troublesome font isn't there, but I still get the error. I've also tried deleting the font from my system via the registry. It's possible this issue comes from the fact that the font in question was previously used in the template, but if it's hidden or embedded already, I'm not sure how to remove it. Any help or advice would be wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Please post your query at answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing the font?

[image]